# Unresolved reference 'streamTable' of DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

The version I am using is 1.30.0.12. The following script cannot identify `streamTable` and reports. [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZU9i.png). Does anyone encounter this type of error before?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Python API of DolphinDB. 1.30.0.12 is the version of the API which is server-based. Do make sure the server is open. For the Python API applications, you can refer to this [tutorial](https://github.com/dolphindb/Tutorials_EN/blob/master/python_api.md).

There are two ways to create a stream table in python.

```
import dolphindb as ddb
s=ddb.session()
# connect to DolphinDB server
s.connect("localhost", 8848, "admin", "123456")

# first method, pass the parameters directly 
s.run("""streamTable(100:10, ["Name", "Age"], ["string", "int"])""")

# second method, create a stream table after importing the varaibles
colName=["Name", "Age"]
colType=["string", "int"]
s.upload({'colName': colName})
s.upload({'colType': colType})
s.run("streamTable(100:10, colName, colType)")
```